# BitBucket - "Conflicts must be resolved before you merge", but I have no conflicts

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm attempting to merge from master into a branch.  I initially had some conflicts which I have now resolved.  However, Bitbucket is still preventing me from merging, but shows no conflicts anymore.  I tried deleting the pull request and creating a new one, but I'm getting the same thing.

So, how do I resolve conflicts when there are no more conflicts?

Comment: Did you take a pull from correct branch?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes.

Comment: It's pretty hard to help without seeing more information… can you link to the repository?